# jquery object get() returns [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called setColor() which creates an element and returns it as a jquery object. Now when I try to use the returned value ( which I get from `v=setColor().get(0)`) if I append `v` by itself, it's fine, but when I use this :

`props.append('<li><span>'+this+'</span> : <span class="property ">'+ v +'</span> </li>');`

I get `[object HTMLInputElement]`inserted instead. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why would you expect something different? `get(0)` grabs the DOM element from the jQuery collection, which seems to be an input field. What do you want `v` to be?

Comment: I want it to insert the HTML source there @elclanrs

Comment: Then you need to use `html()` on the jQuery object, or `innerHtml` on the DOM element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert an element to a string in that context. Try this instead.

```
props.append('<li><span></span> : <span class="property"></span></li>');
props.find('span').eq(0).append(this);
props.find('.property').append(v);
```

Answer (score 2):

v.html() will return the inner html for the jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` can accept any of `htmlString` or `Element`or`jQuery` but can not use the combination of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

Get() returns the jquery object. 
so either you need to use html() method or innerHTML

```
v.html() 

or 

v.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('<li><span>' + this + '</span> :  </li>').append($('<span class="property "></span>').append(v)).appendTo(props)
```